# Is there any SIP (VoIP) client library for React Native?

Tags: react-native, mobile, sip, voip, pjsip

I am implementing a product with react native and I need to connect the app with an Asterisk server by SIP protocol, I search for some library in react native who could help me to perform a VoIP call and nothing found. Is anyone facing the same problem who can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same as me, I found react-native-pjsip. But the library was not updated till 3 years ago. And the documentation is very confusing for me.

PS: I still looking, the way to connecting my SIP server to my react native app.

Comment: Any code suggestions please

Answer (score 0):

We have successfully released React Native mobile app (Android only) with react-native-pjsip. It works as expected. SIP server is Asterisk. We are planning to release iOS soon.

Comment: I am planning to create a voip over react native and need your suggestion is it worth depending on react-native-pjsip which was not updated since years